# AWS - Load balance for 443 requests but using the server's ssl certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl, load-balancing

I want set up AWS load balancing on my EC2 instance, but I have a kind of dynamic SSL certificate management on it, and because of that, I need use the server's SSL certificate instead of setting up a certificate on the load balancer. Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of LB you use? DO the LB have option to balance on TCP instead of SSL/TLS?

Comment: Im using AWS LB. Yes, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to terminate SSL/TLS connection on the web servers (and not on the LB(s) ) you can set LB to balance TCP connection and not SSL/TLS. Of cource this have some disadvantages but based on your requirements this seems to be the only way.

BTW if you have only one web server/service it is strange for me you want to balance it. LB is normally applied when you have more than one.

Comment: I see. Then should i setup a TCP load balancing targeting the target group on both port 80 and 443, so my server can handle this?

Comment: IMHO you should not mix 80 and 443 ports. You can create two balances, one for each port.

Comment: Right. Should i do this making the listener at tcp 80 point to the instance's 80 and listener tcp 443 point to the instance's 443?

Comment: Correct. As port 80 do not need termination you can use http instead of tcp

Comment: I created a tcp load balance, set a tcp listener at 443 targeting my ec2 instance 443 too, but im facing a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error when i try a https request.

Comment: @adrianosmateus, this mean some mismatch of DNS cache records. Please create new question about this.

Comment: I fixed the DNS issue. Thanks for the help!